# Creating a nested table

Tags: sql

create a nested table object type named TRANSCRIPT that contains the following enrollment information for student: COURSE.COURSE_NO, COURSE.DESCRIPTION, ENROLLMENT.ENROLL_DATE and ENROLLMENT.FINAL_G.

```
CREATE TABLE transcript
AS (SELECT course_no, description
FROM course
UNION SELECT enroll_date, final_grade FROM enrollment);
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: is this the best method to do this task?  Also I keep getting an error that the the datatype must be the same as the corresponding expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table needs to be defined as the type of columns that are in the table, what you are doing here is mixing the data to be stored in the table with the table definition.  For instance you may define the two tables like such, and then fill them with data using an `insert`

```
CREATE TABLE transcript as
    transcript_id int identity(1,1),
    enroll_date datetime,
    final_grade char(1),
    student_id int

CREATE TABLE course as 
    course_no int,
    description varchar(25)

INSERT INTO transcript (enroll_date, final_grade, student_id) values('1/1/2019', 'A', 10)
```